# Converting Case Classes with params as Case Classes to Avro Message to send to Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I am using case class which has nested case classes and `Seq[Nested Case Classes]`
The problem is when I try to serialize it using `KafkaAvroSerializer` it throws:

````
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Avro type. Supported types are null, Boolean, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, byte[] and IndexedRecord
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.getSchema(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.java:115)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:71)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:879)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:841)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:728)```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Avro with Scala constructs like case classes I recommend you use [Avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s). This has native support for all scala features and can even create the schema from your model if that is what you want.

There are some gotcha's with automatic type class derivation. This is what I learned.

Use at least avro4s version 2.0.4

Some of the macros generate code with compiler warnings and also break wart remover. We had to add the following annotations to get our code to compile (sometimes the error is cannot find implicit, but its caused by error in macro generated code):

```
@com.github.ghik.silencer.silent
@SuppressWarnings(Array("org.wartremover.warts.Null", "org.wartremover.warts.AsInstanceOf", "org.wartremover.warts.StringPlusAny"))
```

Next automatic type class derivation only works one level at a time. I created an object to hold all my `SchemaFor`, `Decoder` and `Encoder` instances for my schema. Then I built up the type classes instances explicitly starting from the inner most types. I also used `implicitly` to verify each ADT would resolve before moving to the next one.  For example:

```
sealed trait Notification
object Notification {
  final case class Outstanding(attempts: Int) extends Notification
  final case class Complete(attemts: Int, completedAt: Instant) extends Notification
}

sealed trait Job
final case class EnqueuedJob(id: String, enqueuedAt: Instant) extends Job
final case class RunningJob(id: String, enqueuedAt: Instant, startedAt: Instant) extends Job
final case class FinishedJob(id: String, enqueuedAt: Instant, startedAt: Instant, completedAt: Instant) extends Job

object Schema {

  // Explicitly define schema for ADT instances
  implicit val schemaForNotificationComplete: SchemaFor[Notification.Complete] = SchemaFor.applyMacro
  implicit val schemaForNotificationOutstanding: SchemaFor[Notification.Outstanding] = SchemaFor.applyMacro

  // Verify Notification ADT is defined
  implicitly[SchemaFor[Notification]]
  implicitly[Decoder[Notification]]
  implicitly[Encoder[Notification]]

  // Explicitly define schema, decoder and encoder for ADT instances
  implicit val schemaForEnqueuedJob: SchemaFor[EnqueuedJob] = SchemaFor.applyMacro
  implicit val decodeEnqueuedJob: Decoder[EnqueuedJob] = Decoder.applyMacro
  implicit val encodeEnqueuedJob: Encoder[EnqueuedJob] = Encoder.applyMacro

  implicit val schemaForRunningJob: SchemaFor[RunningJob] = SchemaFor.applyMacro
  implicit val decodeRunningJob: Decoder[RunningJob] = Decoder.applyMacro
  implicit val encodeRunningJob: Encoder[RunningJob] = Encoder.applyMacro

  implicit val schemaForFinishedJob: SchemaFor[FinishedJob] = SchemaFor.applyMacro
  implicit val decodeFinishedJob: Decoder[FinishedJob] = Decoder.applyMacro
  implicit val encodeFinishedJob: Encoder[FinishedJob] = Encoder.applyMacro

  // Verify Notification ADT is defined
  implicitly[Encoder[Job]]
  implicitly[Decoder[Job]]
  implicitly[SchemaFor[Job]]

  // And so on until complete nested ADT is defined
}
```

Comment: I am already using avro4s but I don't think it supports parsing nested case classes

Comment: @KumarKavish I have expanded my answer with all the details of how I got avro4s to work.

Comment: avro4s definitely supports nested case classes.

Comment: It does, but if your ADTs are nested too deep the implicit resolution diverges. My typed are more deeply nested than my example. Often the only sign of this is a missing implicit for some of your sealed traits, hence I verify at each level. Finally the macros generate code with warnings and line failures, this can silently effect implicit resolution too.